# Difference between bad block, bad sector and bad cluster? repairing

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

So recently my system (win7 64) started running strange.
Open file dialog broken, random service crashes, .
Throughout the day the system was getting less and less stable until continuous blue screens occurred.
event log showd ideport0 problems.
chkdsk showed the fileystem as clean.  Everything in windows shows the HD as clean except for a HD monitoring program which reported "pending sector count" and "uncorrectable sector count" as yellow.

Seatools for windows found errors and suggested to run Seatools for Dos.

I ran the long test and it found bad sectors.  It gave me the option to repair these.  which it did.
Now a day later everything seems to be fine.

How exactly does Sea Tools for DOS fix these bad sectors?  Does it just mark them as bad to be never used again?  Does this mean it was a soft failure of the disk instead of a hard (physical) ?
Why was S.M.A.R.T never triggered?

tia.

Comment: Your traditional magnetic hdd has spare sectors it uses when a primary sector goes bad.  It moves the data on the bad partition if it can to this backup sector.  Your hdd is failing you should think about purchasing a replacement hdd.